# Internet Explorer version 6 and 7 - min-width issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I;m trying a workaround for ie 6 for min-width.

See the code below

```
  <!--[if lte IE 6]>
  <style type="text/css">
 .left_2 {width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 137? "135px": "21.5%" )  !important; padding-left:7.5px; padding-right:7.5px; height:auto; float:left;}
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
  .left_2 {  min-width:135px; width:21.5%; padding-left:7.5px; padding-right:7.5px; height:auto; float:left; }
  </style>
```

However this doesn't seem to have any effect both for ie6 and ie7..  i even set the doctype to strict to make this work for ie 7...what's wrong?

EDIT: Is this what you mean?

```
  <style type="text/css">
  .left_2 {  min-width:135px; width:21.5%; padding-left:7.5px; padding-right:7.5px; height:auto; float:left; }
  </style>


  <!--[if lte IE 6]>
  <style type="text/css">
 .left_2 {width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 137? "135px": "21.5%" ) !important;}
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

What IE6 sees:

> Set "width" to the result of an expression
>   Set "width" to 21.5%

Put the conditional comment after the regular style, not before.

Comment: I can't read it too well in the unformatted comment box, but that looks about right.

Comment: i tried that.. it still doesn't work... what i did there was shift the styling meant for all modern browsers at the top and the  conditional styling for IE 6 below the normal styling... Is that right?

Comment: Please see the edit section of the question... I put the formatted changes there.

Comment: well i googled that and expression is meant for ms -ie rendering engine... and it seems that's how it's used but it's not working the way it is meant to at the moment